# Installing FontForge from the source on GitHub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, fonts

I'm trying to install the latest version of [FontForge](https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge) from the source. I know the whole procedure of `./configure`, `make`, and `make install`, but there's no configure script in the source package, just `configure.ac`, which seemingly needs to be processed with `autoconf`, but `autoconf` fails to do so. When I run `autoconf`, it says something about possibly undefined macro. After I googled the error, it led me to trying `aclocal ; autoheader; automake ; autoconf` which didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the `autogen.sh` script to generate the `configure` script. As a pre-requisite, you would need `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool` installed.

```
$ ./autogen.sh

Preparing the fontforge build system...please wait

Found GNU Autoconf version 2.69
Found GNU Automake version 1.12.1
Found GNU Libtool version 2.4.2

Automatically preparing build ... done

The fontforge build system is now prepared.  To build here, run:
  ./configure
  make
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run the [`autogen.sh`](https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/blob/master/autogen.sh) script, it will perform all the necessary steps. See the [Auto-Book](http://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_43.html) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The configure script isn't present in the git master; that's normal. To create it, run

```
./autogen.sh
```

I've added an INSTALL.git file to the git repo so this will be clear to other users.

https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/blob/master/INSTALL.git